# Python3 urlopen get "504 Gateway timeout" on localhost(127.0.0.1)

Tags: python, http, urllib

I got a 504 gateway timeout when use urlopen to open a site on localhost,while my browser can open it normally.

This site is on localhost and I can use my browser to prove that it works fine. I try to enable and disable system proxy settings but it has no effect.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlopen("http://127.0.0.1") 
#raise urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add `http://` before `127.0.0.1`. Second, give us more information on the server you are running, like, are you using proxy for localhost?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that urllib.request.urlopen in python3.7 don't understand subnet like 127.0.0.0/8 in no_proxy environment variable. Now I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 and it works.